# Unity Container Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, unity-container, enterprise-library

Hi I´m working on a project that uses Enterprice Libraries´s Unity container to resolve 
dependencies for exception handling, cache, logging and db access but we keep getting a lot of leaked objects into memory.

We are using property injection like this:

```
[Dependency]
public Database DB
{
  get { return db; }
  set { db = value; }
}
[Dependency]
public ExceptionManager ExceptionMgr
{
  get { return exceptionManager; }
  set { exceptionManager = value; }
}
```

Some of the object leaked:

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSetti
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionPolicyData
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ReplaceHandlerData
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.WrapHandlerData                               Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.GenericEnumeratorWrapper                                 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerData                                                                                                       Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheStorageData

Any general advice on handling dependencies with Unity to avoid object leaks?

Comment: How are you confirming the memory leaks? Can you post some more stats that show your memory profile before and after the "leak"? One thing to note with Unity is that, by default, objects don't get disposed from the container until the container itself is disposed. This is the SingeltonLifetimeManager behavior. If you want control the lifetime of your objects you will have to sue a different lifetime manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the objects you list are part of the configuration system. How are you initializing your container? Just calling "AddNewExtension()?" If so, it's not really a leak, since those objects represent the configuration you loaded. The configuration source (which is what's holding on to those objects) stays around for the life of the app so that it can watch for, and notify you, of changes in your application.

What tools are you running that are telling you they're leaking? And are the leaks growing, or constant? Some details would help narrow down the behavior from "expected" to "whoops actual bug".

Also, this is more an Enterprise Library question than a Unity one - Unity itself doesn't leak that I know of.

Comment: So if I initialize the container multiple times the configuration objects for each initialization will stay around for the entire app life?

Comment: Basically yes. There are some tricks you can use to mitigate this. For example, create a container and initialize Entlib in it, then use a child container for everything else. Then drop and reinitialize the child container. That would prevent reloading the Entlib config stuff. You could also try explicitly creating the ConfigurationSource object, configuring the container with it, and then disposing it once the container is configured. Not sure it would work or help, though.

Answer (score -3):

Are you disposing the Database instance properly? Like for example (using db = new Database()) { .... } ?

Comment: This misses the point of enterprise library. EL manages the dependencies like the db for you. You tell it you want an instance of your class and it gives you one with the dependency fulfilled. When you dispose of your class it deals with the disposition of the dependencies.